# Need PowerShell script to automatically hide disabled users from GAL in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm looking for a PS script that will automatically hide all disabled users from the GAL. I ran the below command but it didn't actually hide anything so I'm thinking I must be missing something.

```
get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where{$_.UserAccountControl -eq "AccountDisabled, NormalAccount" -and $_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $True
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out (haven't run it myself):

```
Import-Module C:\Temp\Exchange.psm1
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
$users = ([adsiSearcher]$Filter).findall()
foreach($suser in $users)
    {
    if($suser.properties.item("showInAddressBook") -ne $null) {
        get-mailbox "$($suser.properties.item("sAMAccountName"))" | ? {$_.RecipientType -eq "UserMailbox"} | set-mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $True
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Run this in the Powershell ISE, not the Exchange Management Shell.
- You will need to change the "Import-Module" line at the top to point
  to the Exchange.psm1 file on your Exchange management machine for
  this to work.
- I would try just printing the user accounts that you are going to
  hide first to make sure it is going to affect the users you think
  it is before you configure their mailboxes. (Put a `#` before the pipe to set-mailbox to comment that part out)

Comment: About to head out for the day but I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know if it does the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Beware that this will work for Disabled Users, as in: Disabled in Active Directory, not for active users with disabled mailboxes :-)